# Move Window Form with the help of javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I am using MFC HTML Dialog. I remove tool window from windows form. Now i want to create some button or something to control the position of Windows form with mouse in javascript or html. How i do that any idea?

I try this code:

```
function moveWidow() {

            setTimeout(function () {
                this.resizeTo(400, 300);
                this.moveTo(0, 300);
            }
      , 100);
        }

HRESULT CMFCApplication7Dlg::OnButtonOK(IHTMLElement* /*pElement*/)
{
    /*CStringArray arrArgs;
    CComVariant varRes;
    //arrArgs.Add(_T("1"));//you can add value to CStringArray 
    //arrArgs.Add(_T("2"));//if your javascript function having any arguments
    CallClientScript(L"myfunction1", &arrArgs, &varRes);

    OnOK();
    return S_OK;*/

    CStringArray arrArgs;
    CComVariant varRes;
    CallClientScript(L"moveWindow", &arrArgs, &varRes);
    return 0;
}
```